# Getting exception java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, hsqldb

I tride to Run the following code in eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection = null;  
    ResultSet resultSet = null;  
    Statement statement = null;  

    try {  
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/URLAccess", "SA", "");  
        statement = connection.createStatement();  
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT referrer FROM Access");  
        while (resultSet.next()) {  
            System.out.println("referrer : "+ resultSet.getString("referrer"));  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        try {  
            resultSet.close();  
            statement.close();  
            connection.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

but i am getting following exception
can anyone suggest...

```
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at testdriver.Hsqldb.main(Hsqldb.java:20)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testdriver.Hsqldb.main(Hsqldb.java:30)
```

WHat i was trying to do is run this query to get details of the table(access) in my Hypersql DB and while trying to run the above code i got the above exception.

Please help on this regard. Looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: You need to specify the port no. in the connection string. E.g. `localhost:5506`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting this error because the hsql server is not started. I am not familiar with this but I found this command to start the server:

```
java -classpath ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server
```

Check out the last post in this [question](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=951268). Also check out the hsql [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html). Lastly, [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html) is more on running hsql server.